# javafx Run time failure

Tags: java, javafx

Hello guys I've been developing a JavaFx Application on NetBeans 8.2 and Gluon Scene Builder. İnitially program gives me a output. After developing I received errors.

(I tried so many advices on this platform, I clean and build the project, I change my fxml file location, I delete and re-upload Scene Builder, I even delete whole project and write down again to see if I'm forgetting something. The program does not contain any syntax errors. Both my server and client are working. The error occurs when JavaFXMLApplication.java is run)

I probably have something missing, not wrong.

*User variables for HP*

```
PATH:   C:\Users\HP\Envs\gui; C:\Users\HP\Desktop\jdk-11.0.2
```

*System Variables*

```
PATH:C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Program 
Files\Python37\;C:\Users\HP\Envs\gui;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin
```

*My fxml file*

```xml
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="javafxmlapplication.FXMLDocumentController">
```

*The code :*

```
package javafxmlapplication;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXMLApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource
    ("/src/javafxmlapplication/fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,900,600);

        stage.setTitle("GUI");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Random rand = new Random();
                int myrand = rand.nextInt(15)+1;
                System.out.println((myrand+1)+"blue");
                root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(myrand).setStyle("-fx-background-color: #001f3f");
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e){
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(myrand).setStyle("-fx-background-color : #FF4136");
            }
        },0,1000);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

In the error message system marks this line but give no error on the row numbers(I tried add getClassLoader() it gave me the same error)

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource
    ("/src/javafxmlapplication/fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

My system have positive output with java and javac codes in the cmd.

```
Executing C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXMLApplication\dist\run1672502609\JavaFXMLApplication.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application javafxmlapplication.JavaFXMLApplication
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXMLApplication\dist\run1672502609
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

This below error

```
javafxmlapplication.JavaFXMLApplication.start(JavaFXMLApplication.java:25)
```

points this

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/src/javafxmlapplication/fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

[image: Project structure]

[image: Scene builder connection]

Any help will be appreciated I'm in a loop.

Comment: a) do not modify the GUI from a background thread. If you want to implement updating the gui from a `TimerTask`, use `Platform.runLater` (be sure to exclude long-running operations like `Thread.sleep` from the runnable; you may need to use `Platform.runLater` twice). `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/javafxmlapplication/fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml"));` should work, unless Netbeans doesn't include the resource or I missed a typo; if it doesn't, use Netbeans's file browser to take a look into the jar produced and check for the resource (`\dist\run***\JavaFXMLApplication.jar`)

Comment: there is no `run***` file man there is just:      web-files file, 
    .html,    jar.jnpl

Comment: It says `Executing C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXMLApplication\dist\run1672502609\JavaFXMLApplication.jar using ...` just above the error you posted. The jar should be around there somewhere...

Comment: Yes there iis a jar file but ı do not know what to this file. Can you clerify it?

Comment: In the version of Netbeans I used you could open the `.jar` file and take a look at it's content using the `Files` tab next to `Projects`. You can use this feature to verify that the fxml is where you want it to be or find out where it's placed. (Keep in mind that the `.`s you see there correspond to `/`s in the resource path and you need to prepend `/` at the front of the path to make `getResource` start the lookup at the root.). This way you can verify that this is not just an issue with the project setup to not include fxml files as resource. (Check the different path first though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong path to load your fxml file. Use `fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml` or `/javafxapplication/fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml`.

> Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class. This method delegates to this object's class loader. If this object was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, the method delegates to ClassLoader.getSystemResource(java.lang.String).
>   Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form: modified_package_name/name

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).

So the following should work:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

Or:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/javafxapplication/fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

Comment: tanks for advice brother but ı tried it also `fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml` parth is automatically created by the system it also do not work for this reason I changed the path. when I compile wtihout the `getClassLoader().` or  path which is created from the system `fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml ` gave me that notifications

Comment: `Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.`